# How to convert date string to Date

Tags: java, date

I have the following string: Feb 16, 2014 2:11:41 PM

I have Googled around for some time now and only see examples on converting strings in the format mmddyyyy.  I can't seem to find out how to convert the format above.

How can I convert this to a Date.
Thanks,
Gary

Comment: by just [google search](https://www.google.com/#q=convert+date+string+to+Date) I found a bunch of exact reference for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below formatter:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE dd,yyyy HH:mm:ss aa");
```

[Also this link would be very helpful](http://www.fileformat.info/tip/java/simpledateformat.htm)

Comment: actually is should be "MMM d, yyyy HH:mm:ss a" which parses without an exception but it brings about a new problem: it converts the PM time to AM!!  I'm posting a new thread on that.